# Overwriting an image upload with Stapler - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, image-uploading

I am wanting to give the user an option to delete their current logo and replace it with a new one. Currently I am using [Stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler), a Laravel package.

I initially had trouble adding the logo, by means of, I had to create the table entity by adding the logo first, and then updating the other fields:

```
$company = Company::create(['logo' => Input::file('logo')]);  
$company->save();

$companyID = $company->id;
$company = Company::find($companyID);

$company->company_name = Input::get('company_name');
```

Now, should a user have selected a new logo to add, I want it to clear the current logo and add the new one. I am struggling on how to add the logo into the same company, as on the code above, the `Company::create` creates a new Company record.

Current code:

Even if I try and `dd()` the file directly, it returns NULL. Its as if it can't even find it within the view!

```
    $logo = Input::file('logo');

    if($logo !== null)
    {
        $company->logo->clear();
        $company->logo = Input::file('logo');;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form wasn't allowing file uploads. By adding:

```
'files'=>'true'
```

into the `Form::open(array(` it added the file.